# xdk button doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, android, button, mobile, intel-xdk

I'm testing my app on a Galaxy Tab 2.
I have a button which looks like this in the code:

```
<button class='msdsBtn' onclick='launchGoogle();'>msds</button>

// test function
function launchGoogle(){
    alertw("launch google");
    intel.xdk.device.launchExternal("http://www.google.com");
}

// wrapper for xdk alert
function alertw(str){           
    intel.xdk.notification.alert(str);
}
```

the button doesn't do *anything*. No errors, no opening of Google, no alert box... nothing.
These buttons are dynamically created on the page. 
Am I missing something? I should note that it all works in the emulator.

Comment: Try plugging your android device in and going to the "Debug" tab.  This will let you do on device debugging with Chrome Developer Tools.  You should be able to see any JS errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the proper plugin ("Notification", I believe, in this case) checked in your project settings?

I wouldn't spend too much time figuring out how to make this call work, as Intel is deprecating the XDK APIs that are redundant with Cordova APIs.

Instead, try switching out your notification calls with the equivelent Cordova method.  It should look something like this:

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])
```

And again, make sure you have the right plugin configured in your project settings ("Dialogs").  Your project settings can be accessed through the XDK IDE by clicking "Projects" in the upper left corner.

Here is the full documentation for the Cordova dialogs API:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md

EDIT: And as Ian says above, you can of course debug your app as it runs on a device through the Debug tab for Android, and with WEINRE on other platforms.